# Virtual Keyboard is behaving abnormally Android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am facing a strange problem: My app behavior is such that when the Activity starts, I requestFocus() on an EditText and show the soft keyboard. Keyboard opens but my layout gets wrong i have only a EditText box in my layout. When requestFocus() on an EditText using:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

app shows 2 edit box overlapping each other. When i manually hide the EditText and then show it layout works normally. I am getting this problem in google nexus while the same code is working correctly in tab 10.1 and tab 7 2.

Comment: Did you try by simply calling the `requestFocus()` method on the **EditText** ?

Comment: yes i tried it now but its not working